# How to add a jquery animation to a single ListViewItem on bind?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, listview

I have a listview wrapped in an UpdatePanel which displays comments from a thread. The update panel is so that when the user submits a new comment, the list rebinds to reflect the new comment without needing to post back. What I want to do is grab the last comment listitem after the rebind and apply a jquery-ui effect to it that will pulsate it a couple times. I'm not exactly sure how to or if i can do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("containername:last-child").animate();
```

where containername is the id of the container holding the listview and .animate() is your jquery-ui effect.

Comment: that addresses the adding of the effect, but finding a way to target the new comment (that was just added) is what's really tricking me. Essentially, I'm rebinding the datasource of the listview. Maybe a selector that grabs the highest list item in the list and attaches this behavior?

Comment: Well, The :last-child should be what is targeting the last item in the list. I assumed that new comments would be put on the bottom of the list. If you have the new comments coming in at the top of the list it should be :first-child instead.